# How to target aspect to method with argument of certain type?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

If I write my aspect

```
@Before("args(data)")
public void beforeMethod( MyParam data ) {
    // ...
}
```

it will handle on method

```
public void m1(MyParam param){};
```

If I write aspect as

```
@Before("args(data,..)")
public void beforeMethod( MyParam data ) {
    // ...
}
```

it will handle on method

```
public void m2(MyParam param, OtherParam param2, Object smthElse){};
```

But `MyParam param` should be first.

The question is: how to configurate `@Before("args(?)")` to match methods where `MyParam param` will be not first parameter like here?

```
@Before("args(?)")
public void m3(OtherParam param2, MyParam param, Object smthElse){};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not test but this might be a way of doing this -

```
args(*, param, ..)
```

Comment: Does this match a single previous parameter or multiple ones?

Comment: this should match a single previous param

Comment: Is there a way to match multiple previous parameters?

Comment: i think it could be done by using by multiple *, before the param

Comment: I'll check and comment then

Comment: it works with asterisk, but I should strictly set number of * before my param. Looks there's no way to use smth like .. as `args(.., param, ..)`